# Some recommendations to develop my own mechanism_model package

Tags: ros, gazebo, transmission, pr2-controller-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Ros Community,

I want to develop my own mechanism_model package to simulate and control in Gazebo. The actuators as you know are primates, but the rotational joints. Then I want you to give me some recommendations on. Besides, Also I want to know if I have to develop my own controller package.

Best Regards,

Carlos Mastalli

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10749/some-recommendations-to-develop-my-own-mechanism_model-package/) by [Carlos Mastalli](https://answers.ros.org/users/592/carlos-mastalli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-07-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-09-08**:
a good place to start is by looking at the http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism and http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_cntrollers stacks.  Let us know if you have more specific questions about design, implementation, etc. of these functionality.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-08-05**:
Perhaps you could clarify your question? What is it that you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

no activity in > 1 month, closing

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0